# How create intermediate proxy system

Tags: c#, windows, proxy, titanium-web-proxy

I want to make an intermediate proxy, I do not need to decrypt the data, but I need to specify a proxy in my browser without a password and login, and the software will connect to the proxy that has login and password verification, all this should work with https support (such like google, youtube), tell me a solution that does not slow down the page loading much and does not give my real address (if I use
ExplicitProxyEndPoint explicitProxyEndPoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint (IPAddress.Parse ("127.0.0.1"), 50000, false);) then all traffic does not go through the specified proxy, if I use true then all sites are loaded VERY long

and if I use TransparentProxyEndPoint, then my browser asks for a username and password from the proxy(and it happens endlessly), how can I avoid this?

i want:
scheme of work:

browser -> local proxy(127.0.0.1:50000) ->my soft -> proxy in internet(ip:port@login:password) -> site
browser <- local proxy(127.0.0.1:50000) <-my soft <- proxy in internet(ip:port@login:password) <- site

I use C# and https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy for Windows

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, using Titanium-Web-Proxy, you need to set up an upstream proxy

```
proxyServer.UpStreamHttpsProxy = new ExternalProxy("your-proxyProvider-Ip", port, "user", "pass");
proxyServer.ForwardToUpstreamGateway = true;
```